# Going live in Youtube by using embedded player in the application is a violation?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am building an app which does live streaming to Youtube channel using an embedded player. So i want to know if it violates the policy of Youtube since I am using a different application to do live to the youtube Also, all the application users will stream to a single youtube channel, so any idea in how many live streams can take place at a time?

Comment: It was stated in the [Broadcast and Stream](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/broadcasts-and-streams#single_encoder) documentation of the YouTube API that "only one event is live at any given time, and the video content for each broadcast is unique". To learn more about policy, you can read the [YouTube API developer policies](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies).

Answer (score 1):

It was stated in the [Broadcast and Stream](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/broadcasts-and-streams#single_encoder) documentation of the YouTube API that "only one event is live at any given time, and the video content for each broadcast is unique". To learn more about policy, you can read the [YouTube API developer policies](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies).